# Invite user as Member

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I'm trying to update my existing app with some new features. App uses Azure B2B API and invites users as guests. It works well, but it causes issues with some emails that marked as mastered in their tenants.

***Is there a way to invite user with user type = Member?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to invite user with user type = Member?

Yes, we could do that with [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph). The default type is Guest,we could change it with the following code. I test it with Microsoft.Graph permission: **Directory.ReadWrite.All**

```
 string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
 string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
 string tenantId = "xxxxxx";
 string clientId = "xxxxxx";
 string secret = "xxxxxx";
 authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
 var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
            var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@odata.type", "microsoft.graph.invitedUserMessageInfo" } };

            Invitation invitation = new Invitation
            {
                InvitedUserEmailAddress = "email",
                InvitedUserMessageInfo = new InvitedUserMessageInfo { AdditionalData = dic },
                InvitedUserDisplayName = "tomsun-member",
                SendInvitationMessage = false,
                InviteRedirectUrl = "http://localhost",
                InvitedUserType = "Member" //Change the Invited User Type 
            };
            var result = graphserviceClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation).Result;
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

**Check it from Azure portal:**

[image]

**Update:**

Add permission from Azure portal

[image]

Check the access token permission with https://jwt.io/

[image]

**Update2:**

Add the packages.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.19.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Having Unauthorized error from Graph API. I have Directory.ReadWrite.All enabled as delegated permission.

Comment: If you use the Azure registriy AD  App, you need to check the Application permission.

Comment: Thanks. I marked your post as answer. I set "Read and write directory data" (which I think the same as Directory.ReadWrite.All). But still have Unauthorized error. Do you have any ideas why I might have this 401 error for Member user type? P.S. I can create separate ticket for this.

Comment: If you use the delegated permission, please have a try to set the user as `Global administrator`. If you use the Application permission, please also don't forget to click grant permssion button on the azure portal.

Comment: `I set "Read and write directory data" (which I think the same as Directory.ReadWrite.All)` You are right. I also update the answer with how to grant permission and how to check access token with https://jwt.io/

Comment: Please check my App Registration permissions - http://prntscr.com/jfm087 Do you think it's correct?

Comment: Not Windows Azure directory AD, please use the Microsoft graph

Comment: I have same configured in Microsoft Graph section - http://prntscr.com/jfm107. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170668/discussion-between-tom-sun-and-vnuuk).

Comment: @TomSun What will be the parameter in Authority URL ?

Comment: @Jagadesh From the code, we could know that the Authority url is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`

Answer (score 1):

Just a second answer to Tom's .

Yes, you can invite a user to be a member in your Tenant. **But I don't recommend you do this unless it's neccessary.**

Solution:

**by PowerShell**

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress "test@contoso.com" -InviteRedirectUrl https://myapps.microsoft.com -InvitedUserDisplayName 'TestUser' -InvitedUserMessageInfo $messageInfo -InvitedUserType member -SendInvitationMessage $true
```

**by Microsoft Graph API**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 161

{"invitedUserEmailAddress":"test@contoso.com","sendInvitationMessage":true,"inviteRedirectUrl":"http://myapps.onmicrosoft.com","invitedUserType":"member"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry - why it's not recommended?

Comment: Hi,@Vnuuk . If you invite an External user as a member, it may caused by users miexed when you manger users. Generally, only verfied domain and `.onmicrosoft` used as members' domain. When we manager users, we are clear to classify them.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense.